# Regex to parse C/C++ functions declarations

Tags: c#, c++, regex, function, header

I need to parse and split C and C++ functions into the main components (return type, function name/class and method, parameters, etc).

I'm working from either headers or a list where the signatures take the form:

> public: void __thiscall myClass::method(int, class myOtherClass * )

I have the following regex, which works for most functions:

```
(?<expo>public\:|protected\:|private\:) (?<ret>(const )*(void|int|unsigned int|long|unsigned long|float|double|(class .*)|(enum .*))) (?<decl>__thiscall|__cdecl|__stdcall|__fastcall|__clrcall) (?<ns>.*)\:\:(?<class>(.*)((<.*>)*))\:\:(?<method>(.*)((<.*>)*))\((?<params>((.*(<.*>)?)(,)?)*)\)
```

There are a few functions that it doesn't like to parse, but appear to match the pattern. I'm not worried about matching functions that aren't members of a class at the moment (can handle that later). The expression is used in a C# program, so the `<label>`s are for easily retrieving the groups.

I'm wondering if there is a standard regex to parse all functions, or how to improve mine to handle the odd exceptions?

Comment: Exactly what do you need to parse?  It looks like you're parsing function declarations, not functions themselves.  Is this standard C and C++ syntax, or some other form?

Comment: It is function declarations, I mis-typed in the title.

Comment: There are command-line tools like ctag that do the job. For instance: 
ctags --c++-kinds=f -x myfile.h

Comment: Compilers 101: C++ is not a regular language, it is not even representable with a context-free grammar. You **cannot** parse it using a regular expression, not even the Perl-based/inspired regular expressions on steroids.

Comment: @Juliano: C++ itself may not be a regular language, but function declarations certainly appear to follow some pretty regular patterns. I'm not worried about parsing the bodies or the language as a whole, simply declarations.

Comment: @karlphillip: I tried SWIG, briefly, but it didn't work out so well. ctag looks like it might be what I'm looking for though, I'll see if it works.

Comment: Bear in mind that functions don't have to have predefined types as return types.  Even in C, any identifier can be a return type (think `typedef`).  FWIW, I've never seen class names prefaced by `class`.  Offhand, it's likely to be legal, but you aren't going to see it.

Comment: @David: True. Your first point I forgot about, and might explain why some functions were being missed. As for the `class` in a type, it would be illegal but that's actually not from headers, it's from a list of functions another program spits out (which indicates classes, enums, etc by prefixing them with the appropriate keyword). I strip those out later.

Comment: @peachykeen: function declarations depend on types, which are defined dynamically during parsing stage by enums, structs, classes and typedefs. This alone makes it a context-sensitive grammar. Add to that template definitions and see where do you get.

Comment: @peachykeen: The fact that a function can have an arbitrary number of arguments alone means that declarations don't form a regular language.

Comment: @Oli: Function declarations don't form a regular language for a few reasons, but arbitrary number of arguments is not one of them. This is easily accomplished with a Kleene Closure.

Comment: Let's say I decided to scrap processing from headers and simply use the lists created by my other program (which prints out DLL exports). All the export-lists are of the form I have in the question. Typedefs are replaced with their actual type, classes/structs/enums are always prefixed as such, templates are always explicitly given, etc. Now, treat all parameters as a single unit (everything between the parentheses is the param-list). Would that, then, become regular enough to have a single expression parse it? I'm trying to avoid doing the parsing by hand, so having to tweak a few is fine.

Comment: small follow up, 12 years later, did you come up with a good enough solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is notoriously hard to parse; it is impossible to write a regex that catches all cases. For example, there can be an unlimited number of nested parentheses, which shows that even this subset of the C++ language is not regular.

But it seems that you're going for practicality, not theoretical correctness. Just keep improving your regex until it catches the cases it needs to catch, and try to make it as stringent as possible so you don't get any false matches.

Without knowing the "odd exceptions" that it doesn't catch, it's hard to say how to improve the regex.

Comment: On the other hand, popular regex implementation are perfectly fine with matching non-regular languages. For example, it is possible to write a regex which matches an infinite deep nested pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), it is a boost library that allows the implementation of recursive descent parsers using only C++ code and no preprocessors. You have to specify a [BNF Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), and then pass a string for it to parse. You can even generate an Abstract-Syntax Tree (AST), which is useful to process the parsed data.

The BNF specification looks like for a list of integers or words separated might look like :

```
using spirit::alpha_p;
using spirit::digit_p;
using spirit::anychar_p;
using spirit::end_p;
using spirit::space_p;

// Inside the definition...
integer    = +digit_p;                      // One or more digits.
word       = +alpha_p;                      // One or more letters.
token      = integer | word;                // An integer or a word.
token_list = token >> *(+space_p >> token)  // A token, followed by 0 or more tokens.
```

For more information refer to the documentation, the library is a bit complex at the beginning, but then it gets easier to use (and more powerful).

Answer (score 0):

No.  Even function prototypes can have arbitrary levels of nesting, so cannot be expressed with a single regular expression.

If you really are restricting yourself to things very close to your example (exactly 2 arguments, etc.), then could you provide an example of something that doesn't match?

Comment: The .NET regex flavor is the only flavor so far that *can* have arbitrary levels of nesting. But using it for this type of job, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Abel: The .Net regex "flavor" is recursive and does backtracking (thus it is not a DFA). This was copied from Perl, which exists since many and many years before .Net was invented.

Comment: @Juliano, not sure what your point is. Indeed, both Perl and .NET are NFA, as are most regex flavors. .NET never made a secret that it follows Perl-syntax closely. But .NET introduced [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) which is what I meant with *arbitrary levels of nesting*. It keeps track of the number of opened vs closed parentheses (or anything) and only succeeds the match if the opening and closing pairs are of the same amount and paired. So far, afaik, .NET is the only flavor that supports this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with NFA/DFA. Even an NFA can only recognize a regular language, and it is possible to transform an NFA into a DFA (though the number of states may grow exponentially). Perl/.NET regex instead have limited support of context-free language parsing, which corresponds to a [pushdown automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).