# What regular expressions can I use in c++,using regex, to parse separators,operators,identifiers, and real numbers?

Tags: c++, regex, expression, lexical

```
  for(int k = 0 ; k < 5.25;k++)
     {
      cout<<"hello"<<endl;
      }
    return 0;
```

I'm writing a c++ program for lexical analysis on a simple text file containing
      c++ code. For example

Then, after the program has extracted the code from the file, it will output to
      the console:

```
   for: keyword
     (: separator
     int: keyword
     k: identifier
     =: operator
     0: integer
     ;: separator
     k: identifier
     <: operator
     5.25: real
     and so forth.
    I already have "(\\w+)" for words, "(\\d+)" for integers, however I don't
    know how to write any of the rest.
```

To give you an idea of what my actual code looks like for a regular expression, here it is.

```
     void lexical_integer(string seq)
     {

regex digits("(\\d+)");
regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), digits);
regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

for (; itd != end; ++itd)
{
    cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" integer"<< endl;
}
     }
```

I'm looking for regular expressions that I can use with regex in c++
        so
        words: "(\w+)" 
        integers:"(\d+)"
        separators: ?
        operators: ? 
        real numbers: ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. Do you just need help writing regular expressions? The C++ standards document explains the format for operators, etc. You just have to convert the BNF into a regex.

Comment: Have you considered using [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/libs/wave/) rather than regular expressions? (Certainly it would be more accurate...)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do lexical analysis. Would you like to use an actual tool for that?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409210/regex-to-parse-c-c-functions-declarations

Comment: This is just tokenization, which is not so bad. It's not full parsing, which is really really hard.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I downloaded Gold parser, and I inserted the BNF grammar, however there are errors and I really don't know what I'm doing. My professor said that I am limited to only those tools that uses Finite state machines(meaning things like regex).

Comment: yes Raymond, i just mainly need help writing Regular expressions in c++ so I can take out the basic operators and separators from a line that I pass to the function I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Regex's are going to be hard to get right because there's some state/context that needs to be maintained while tokenizng. It's best that you read the input character by character and build tokens manually.

Here's what would work for C (more on C++ later):

If you see `/` then you need to look ahead and if there's another `/`, you skip everything until the end of line.

If `/` is followed by `*`, you skip everything until another `*`, if the next after `*` char isn't `/`, you go back to skipping until `*`, you end when you've matched the opening `/*` with the closing `*/`.

With something like that you skip all comments.

If it's `/` not followed by `/` or `*`, you need to additionally check if it's followed by `=` to distinguish between `/` and `/=`.

If you see any of these, it's a token: `,;?:()[]{}`.

If you see `!` you need to look ahead because it can be either `!` or `!=`.
If you see `*` you need to look ahead because it can be either `*` or `*=`.
If you see `%` you need to look ahead because it can be either `%` or `%=`.
If you see `^` you need to look ahead because it can be either `^` or `^=`.
If you see `~` you need to look ahead because it can be either `~` or `~=`.

If you see `+` you need to look ahead because it can be either `+` or `++` or `+=`.

If you see `-` you need to look ahead because it can be either `-` or `--` or `-=` or `->`.

If you see `<` you need to look ahead because it can be either `<` or `<=` or `<<` or `<<=`.
If you see `>` you need to look ahead because it can be either `>` or `>=` or `>>` or `>>=`.

If you see `&` you need to look ahead because it can be either `&` or `&&` or `&=`.
If you see `|` you need to look ahead because it can be either `|` or `||` or `|=`.

If you see `L` (or lowercase `l`) you need to look ahead because it can start a literal character or string constant `L'c'` or `L"string"`. Otherwise, it's a start of some identifier.

If you see `_` or an ASCII letter from `a` to `z` or from `A` to `Z`, it's a start of some identifier. After this can follow an arbitrary number of underscores, letters or decimal digits. The identifiers parsed in this way have to be additionally checked against the set of the reserved keywords such as `int`, `const`, `if`, `switch`, etc etc.

If you see a decimal digit from `0` to `9`, you have multiple options: octal integer constant, decimal integer constant, hexadecimal integer constant, floating-point constant. You should be able to figure out how to parse them similarly to the above. Remember that the constants can be suffixed with `U`, `UL`, `ULL`, `L`, `LL` and `F`.

If you see `.` you need to look ahead because it can be either `.` or `...` or something like `.5`.

I'm not going to describe parsing and tokenizing of literal character or string constants, there's some more logic inside with escape sequences and more.

Now, in C++ you have to additionally parse things like: `::` (extension of `:` parsing), `.*` (extension of `.` parsing), `->*` (extension of `-` parsing) and many more reserved words (e.g. `new`, `virtual`, etc etc and the odd ones like `and`, `bitor` and `not_eq`).

And there's a surprise in C++. The template angle brackets are now allowed to go together without any spaces in-between:

```
X<Y<Z> >
```

can now be legally written as:

```
X<Y<Z>>
```

and the parser must understand enough of this template business to figure out that the last `>>` is two separate `>`'s.

There are also some preprocessor-related tokens (e.g. `#` and `##`, `include`, `ifdef`, `if`, `undef`, etc) and ugly trigraph sequences. And, of course, there's line-concatenation with `\`.

It's a fun little (or not so little) project, which you can do w/o much of trouble, especially if you restrict the accepted variety of inputs.

At any rate, you really need to implement some state machines in the process, however simple they may be (and most will be simple).