# Automatically adding function prefixes to C++ functions

Tags: c++, cuda, metaprogramming

I'm porting a small C++ codebase to callable on the graphics card, via CUDA.
CUDA requires that all functions be prepended with `__host__ __device__` in order to be callable both on the CPU and in GPU kernel code. e.g.,

```
void foo() {} // callable on CPU, not on GPU
__host__ __device__ foo() {} // callable on CPU and on GPU
```

It's a tedious but straight-forward task to add `__host__ __device__` to *every* function in my codebase, but I'm wondering: is there an efficient method to prepend qualifiers to C/C++ functions?

I would be happy with a text-editor technique that detected all function declarations, or with a compiler feature. However, I am unaware of a solution that involves either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such compiler feature.  I'd be wary of broadly applying these directives anyway though, as the calling conventions and stack management might be significantly different (e.g. slower?) than normal host conventions when not needed.  I'd probably put together my own macro , e.g. `#define HDFN __host__ __device__` such that it'd be easy to add/change.

That aside, you might be able to dig up a regex for detecting methods and write a macro simple...

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm hand-annotating everything with a macro. What do you think the regex would look like?

Comment: here's somebody's start for C++ methods: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409210/regex-to-parse-c-c-functions-declarations) you'd have to modify the return types to match the kind of things you're seeing...